# How to explain this warning

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7.19 and after I run `explain` on the following script:

```
explain select a.seller_id AS seller_id, 
       a.seller_name AS seller_name, 
       b.user_name AS user_name, 
       c.state AS state
from a
join b
join c
where((b.seller_name = a.seller_name) and
      (c.user_id = 17) and(b.user_id = 17) and
      (a.gmt_create between ((now() - interval 600 minute)) and ((now() + interval 600 minute)))) 
order by a.gmt_create;
```

Here is the warning message I got:

[image]

To put it into human readable form:

```
select a.seller_id AS seller_id, 
           a.seller_name AS seller_name, 
           b.user_name AS user_name, 
           c.state AS state
    from a
    join b
    join c
    where((b.seller_name = a.seller_name) and
          (c.user_id = 17) and(b.user_id = 17) and
          (a.gmt_create between <cache>((now() - interval 600 minute)) and <cache>((now() + interval 600 minute)))) 
    order by a.gmt_create;
```

What does the `<cache>` tag mean??

Comment: Thanks @CBroe do you mind to answer it and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html):

> - `<cache>`
>
> The expression (such as a scalar subquery) is executed once and the
>   resulting value is saved in memory for later use. For results
>   consisting of multiple values, a temporary table may be created and
>   you will see `<temporary table>` instead.

This means, your calculation of `now() - interval 600 minute` is done only once and the result is used for every row your where clause examines.

Comment: what is the warning message trying to tell me then?

Comment: Consider it just as a note or an info, not a warning. There's nothing bad about this.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway that I can improve my query? I was hoping the explain command could give me some suggestions. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: At a quick glance you're doing a cross join with table c, which is probably not what you want. Put the join conditions in the join clause, e.g. `a join b on b.seller_name = a.seller_name`, not in the where clause. More I can not say with this little information. Post another question with following information: query, explain of the query (the actual explain result, noone cares about warnings), the create table statements (execute `show create table <table_name>\G` for each table and `show indexes from <table_name>;` for each table. But please in another question!